# Json 'Cannot read property 'data' of undefined'

Tags: json, model-view-controller

**My view is:**

```
 function gecmisList() {

        $('#product').jtable({

      title: 'Product List',
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        sorting: true,
        multiSorting: true,
        defaultSorting: 'personelAd Desc',
        actions: {
            listAction: '@Url.Content("~/Product/ProductList")'
        },
        fields: {
            id: {
                title: 'ID',
                width: 'auto',
                list: false,
            },
            startDate: {
                title: 'Start Date',
                width: 'auto'
            },
            entDate: {
                title: 'End Date',
                width: 'auto',
                searchFilter: true
            },
            personelAd: {
                title: 'Personel Name',
                width: 'auto'
            },
            personnelNote: {
                title: 'Personnel Note',
                width: 'auto'
            }

        }

    });
    $('#product').jtable('load');
};
```

when I run my code the view give me this error **'Cannot read property 'data' of undefined'**

What I should do to solve my problem. I am searching but I didnt find nothing to solve it.
I am looking forward for your advice. Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, none of the code you've published is referencing a 'data' property of any object. You need to find where the reference is being made as that is where you will find the thing that is undefined. (e.g. search for '.data')

Comment: Did the error message not come with any hint as to where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I forgot to add key for ID. 
I added **key: true** now it works :)